# Explicitly specify specify string to write to for std::ostringstream

Tags: c++, stl, stream

I have a code, which writes a number to std::string using std::ostringstream:

```
        template<class T>
        class Converter
        {
        private:
            static std::string s_buffer;     
        public:
            static const char* Out(const T& val)
            {
                std::ostringstream os;
                os << val;
                s_buffer = os.str();
                return(s_buffer.data());
            }
        };
```

The `Converter::Out` is called a lot. So much that it even shows up in the profiler. And essentially, what happens here is:

1. An instance of ostringstream is created
2. It creates a buffer to write to and writes to it
3. I copy that buffer to the static string and return it

I think, that if I could get the stream to write directly to the static string, thus avoiding the copy, I may get some performance improvement. But how can I do it - `std::ostringstream` can accept only `const std::string` in constructor, which would be a preliminary fill, not the buffer to write to.
Maybe Boost has some alternative, though I didn't find one... :(

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: It's possible to specify your own buffer by calling [`streambuf::pubsetbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf) and then constructing the stream from that `streambuf`, but it unfortunately gives you a non-resizable buffer.

Comment: @vsoftco I think that's perfectly standard compliant code and I'd expect good implementations to do exactly that. The question is how many implementations actualy do it...

Comment: @jrok, I thought you cannot move from a `std::stringstream`... You can definitely move the returned string (and I think the compiler should do this automatically since `std::string` has a move constructor/assignment operator)

Comment: Have you tried making `std::ostringstream os`also class static? Also, consider changing function signature (& benefit from RVO) by returing `std::string`, caller can call `std::string::c_str()` if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the buffer of an `ostringstream` using the `rdbuf()` method; unfortunately, access to the underlying character buffer is protected. However, you can easily work around that via inheritance:

```
template<class T>
class Converter
{
private:
    static struct Buf : public std::ostringstream, public std::basic_stringbuf<char>
    {
        Buf() { static_cast<std::basic_ios<char>&>(*this).rdbuf(this); }
        void clear() { setp(pbase(), pbase()); }
        char const* c_str() { *pptr() = '\0'; return pbase(); }
    } s_buf;
public:
    static const char* Out(const T& val)
    {
        s_buf.clear();
        s_buf << val;
        return s_buf.c_str();
    }
};
```

If Boost is an option, you can use `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream` backed by a `string` or `vector<char>`: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2012/09/75887.php

Comment: What's the benefit of this over the original program?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it doesn't involve a string copy.

Comment: Wow, the code you suggest really flies! Dropped the total time spent in Converter::Out from 3.5% to 1.5% of the whole execution time. Boost example on the other hand was considerably worse than my original code (13%).